# Multi-vendor with custom shop site for each vendor

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic

What is the best way to create a multi-vendor site that allows user to register as a vendor and not only this but it provides the vendor a new custom shop web-site which he/she can customize by himself/herself. I already found some of the plugins that allows this at some point but i want to have that function that allows vendor to customize their shop too, in a way that they can add categories,add posts, add products on different categories. So basically i want the master page to contain some posts from different vendors, and the child pages(stores) to be customizable from the master page(Have a different look and feel) but the header of master page should retain in the child themes.
Plugins that i found and experimentet with are: 
1. WC vendors
2. YITH 
3. Dokan
4. Marketpress etc.

something like shopify

Comment: Please note that plugin recommendations are off topic here. Currently your question looks  too broad or primarily opinion-based (aka "best way"). It would help if you could narrow it down,to avoid having it closed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Installing [WordPress with multisite enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) could let you do what you want. You could use a plugin to create a "template" site that is used for all new websites.

I used the [Multisite Cloner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-cloner/) plugin to accomplish this very thing on a recent project. You can configure multisite to allow users to choose their own theme. You may want to provide a set of themes that allow the user to change colors or upload their logo.

On my afore-mentioned recent project, there was a requirement that each new shop website needed to share products, I used the [ThreeWP Broadcast Premium Pack](https://plainviewplugins.com/threewp-broadcast-premium-pack/) to push products, pages, and posts to the other multisite instances within the network.

Once a user is customizing their instance, you could use WordPress categories or tags to display/hide certain products, say by creating a category or tag named "hidden" if they don't want to show a certain product post on their site.